# Why is there a difference between scipy.special.comb and math.comb?

Tags: python, math, scipy, comb

Can someone explain why this is not equal please?

```
import scipy
import math
sum(math.comb(250, i) for i in range(0, 251)) == sum(scipy.special.comb(250, i) for i in range(0, 251))
```

But that's, for example, yes?

```
sum(math.comb(25, i) for i in range(0, 26)) == sum(scipy.special.comb(25, i) for i in range(0, 26))
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html) you find, that you have to set the 'exact' flag to True like this:

```
scipy.special.comb(250, i, exact=True)
```

your code will then read

```
import scipy.special as ssp
import math
print(sum(math.comb(250, i) for i in range(0, 251)) == sum(ssp.comb(250, i, exact=True) for i in range(0, 251)))
```

and output 'True'.

The documentation says

> exactbool, optional
>
> If exact is False, then floating point precision is used, otherwise exact long integer is computed.